# LINQ to Entities three table join query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm having a bit trouble with a query in Linq to Entities which I hope someone can shed a light on :-) What I'm trying to do is to create a query that joins three tables.

So far it works, but since the last table I'm trying to join is empty, the result of the query doesn't contain any records. When I remove the last join, it gives me the right results.

My query looks like this:

```
var query = from p in db.QuizParticipants
            join points in db.ParticipantPoints on p.id 
            equals points.participantId into participantsGroup
            from po in participantsGroup
            join winners in db.Winners on p.id 
            equals winners.participantId into winnersGroup
            from w in winnersGroup
            where p.hasAttended == 1 && p.weeknumber == weeknumber
            select new
            {
                ParticipantId = p.id,
                HasAttended = p.hasAttended,
                Weeknumber = p.weeknumber, 
                UmbracoMemberId = p.umbMemberId,
                Points = po.points,
                HasWonFirstPrize = w.hasWonFirstPrize,
                HasWonVoucher = w.hasWonVoucher                                    
            };
```

What I would like is to get some records even if the Winners table is empty or there is no match in it.

Any help/hint on this is greatly appreciated! :-)

Thanks a lot in advance.

/ Bo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set these up as related entities instead of doing joins, I think it will be easier to do what you're trying to do.

```
var query = from p in db.QuizParticipants
            where p.hasAttended == 1 && p.weeknumber == weeknumber
            select new
            {
                ParticipantId = p.id,
                HasAttended = p.hasAttended,
                Weeknumber = p.weeknumber, 
                UmbracoMemberId = p.umbMemberId,
                Points = p.ParticipantPoints.Sum(pts => pts.points),
                HasWonFirstPrize = p.Winners.Any(w => w.hasWonFirstPrize),
                HasWonVoucher = p.Winners.Any(w => w.hasWonVoucher)
            };
```

This is assuming `hasWonFirstPrize` and `hasWonVoucher` are boolean fields, but you can use any aggregate function to get the results you need, such as `p.Winners.Any(w => w.hasWonFirstPrize == 1)`

Comment: Joel, that's just so awesome and clean! And it works :-) thanks a lot. Now onto the hard part: both your answer and cadrell0's actually helped me, so which answer to mark as accepted? What's the policy on stackoverflow?

Comment: If I were the asker, I would upvote both and accept whichever one I ended up using.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use query syntax a lot but I believe you need to change `from w in winnersGroup` to `from w in winnersGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Hi cadrell0, I agree :) I tried it, but it gives me this error: The cast to value type 'Byte' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type. HasWonFirstPrize and HasWonVoucher is indeed byte datatypes, but I don't want them to be null in the database to be honest :-) ?

Comment: You will probably then need to change the assignment of HasWonFirstPrize to something like `HasWonFirstPrize = w == null ? 0 : w.hasWonFirstPrize,`